# Excel Format - less than 1.00 should appear as -

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need an Excel format that displays large currency amounts. I want it to add commas, don't show pennies, and show "-" instead of a zero.

This works:

```
#,##0;-#,##0;-
```

except that .02 appears as "0", and -.02 appears as "-0"

How can I modify it to show "-" for anything between 1 and -1?

Answer (score 1):

Add a conditional format.  If cell_value between 1 and -1, format is "-"